# How to efficiently instantiate an object in a Vue component?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, vue.js

I am trying to instantiate a map that I will use in my calculatePrice method.

```
            calculatePrice(key) {

                let prices = new Map({
                0: 17,
                1: 19,
                2: 24,
                3: 27,
                4: 30,
                5: 46,
                6: 50,
                7: 54,
                8: 58,
                9: 67,
                10: 75,
                });

                let price = prices.get(key);
                return price;
            },
```

However, since I will frequently be calling this method (using @change in a form field), it does not seem optimal for performance to keep making this object every time the method is called. Is there a better place to put "prices" in a view component? Some place it can be instantiated when the page loads, and referenced whenever the method is called without having to be recreated?

Comment: Maybe just put it in an IIFE and then assign a function to `calculatePrice`?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Sorry I am not completely familiar with IIFEs. I think I get what you're saying though. How might you do this if for an input key? How would you do a simple function like get the square root from that key?

Comment: as property of `data` object could be a solution

Comment: `this.calculatePrice = (() => { let prices = ...; return key => prices.get(key) })();`

Comment: @CertainPerformance Isn't this the same thing though? Aren't you creating the object "prices" every time that method is ran?

Comment: No, like that, you create it only once

Comment: There's nothing preventing you from simply storing it as a variable outside of the function. It will be created when the component is created.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Where might be the best place to put it? I am using the data() { return { ... } } which is only for iterable objects IIRC, so I don't think that works.

Comment: @stambden it doesn't need to go in `data` unless you need templates to access it directly. Just define it after the `script` tag.

Comment: @MarkMeyer I seem to get an "object is not iterable" error when I do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like it is a global constant for your component. Create it outside of the component definition, but in the same scope (or import it from another file).

Comment: So essentially, inside the <script> ... </script> tag, but outside of the export default { .. }?

Comment: Sounds right. Different projects have different setups.

Answer (score 0):

Make it part of the `data` property:

```
export default {
    name: 'ComponentName',
    data() {
        return {
            prices: {
                0: 17,
                1: 19,
                2: 24,
                3: 27,
                4: 30,
                5: 46,
                6: 50,
                7: 54,
                8: 58,
                9: 67,
                10: 75,
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        calculatePrice(key) {
            return this.prices[key];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I seem to get "object is not iterable" error when I do this.

Comment: @Stamden I've updated to get rid of the `Map` object. You don't really need it.

Comment: Thank you. I completely forgot that you could make objects like this in JS.

Comment: Just a note - by doing this, you're unnecessarily making `prices` reactive, which doesn't make sense for your use case. I'd go with the suggestion from @Roy J.

Comment: @mzgajner Ah okay. Making it reactive would be less good performance wise, I am assuming?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. To be perfectly honest, the improvement is extremely minor, but then again - so is the one from your original optimization of moving it outside the function.